# Get memory type and speed without sudo

Tags: memory

On CentOS, `lshw` and `dmidecode` can tell you memory type (e.g. DDR3) and speed but need `sudo` or root.

Looks like `/sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc*/dimm*/dimm_mem_type` has the memory type info but not the speed. [Docs](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/mchehab/linux-edac/+/hw_events_v15/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-devices-edac).

Is there a way of getting this same info (memory type and speed) without sudo? E.g. via `/sys`?

Comment: Change permissions on the relevant files.

Comment: Which files would those be? The executables?? That would defeat the point of not needing root access.

Comment: @IporSircer that would not only require root, so isn't a solution to the question asked, it would also be a very, very bad idea. You don't just change permissions of system files at will.

Comment: @lost please [edit] your question and specify what operating systems you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory speed information is only available from DMI.  It's easy to confirm that when lshw looks up the information, it's grabbing it via DMI.  Even when run as root, `lshw -short -C memory -disable dmi` without DMI only knows the total memory.

That means this question is really rephrasing how to get DMI decoding without root.  Two relevant sources:

- [How to get dmidecode information without root privileges?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24212/how-to-get-dmidecode-information-without-root-privileges)
- https://savannah.nongnu.org/support/?109063

To summarize the ideas in those two:

- "If you want to let non-root users access all the DMI information, you could change the permissions of files under /sys/firmware/dmi/tables to 444 (or set the group to something meaningful for your system, and set the permissions to 440) in some init script."
- You can fight with sudo to grant access to dmidecode/lshw.
- If you can alter system startup you could have an init script output the DMI info to a text file somewhere.

But if you don't have some cooperation with root, there is no way to find this out.